# if my database is empty then how will be auto hide my delete button

Tags: php, arrays

If my array value is zero then how will be auto hide my output

```
      <?php if(count($rows) > 0) { ?>

     <div class="apple2">
     Count is: <?PHP echo count($rows);?>
       </div>
     <?php } ?>
     <div class="apple3">
                        <td><input type="button" name="update1" class="btn btn-success"value="Update1" onClick="setUpdateAction();" /> 
                     <input type="submit" name="saved" value="Delete"class="btn btn-success"  /></td>
                 </div>
         <?php
             foreach ($rows as $row_id  => $row)
            {
        ?>
```

Comment: no idea what you are asking

Comment: where's your output?? what you want to hide??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see this, I think you need to check count is greater than zero

```
<?php if(count($rows) > 0) { ?>

    <div class="apple2">
      Count is: <?PHP echo count($rows);?>
     <div class="apple3">
          <td><input type="button" name="update1" class="btn btn-success"value="Update1" onClick="setUpdateAction();" /> 
          <input type="submit" name="saved" value="Delete"class="btn btn-success"  /></td>
     </div>

<?php } ?>
```

Comment: thank you didi and this same time i want to hide my delete button also please help me

Answer (score 0):

```
<?PHP 
  if(count($rows) == 0){
     echo 'nothing';
  }else{
    echo count($rows);
  }
?>
```